# Apply multiple filters JSON API Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonapi-resources

just a simple question which I am unable to figure out. I want to apply multiple filters in `rails JsonApiResources`. Here's the resources code I've.

```
      filters :start_date, :end_date, apply: -> (records, value, _options){
        byebug
        time = ' 00:00:00'
        _options[:context][:current_company].documents.where('updated_at > ? AND updated_at < ?',value[0]+time,value[1]+time)
      }
```

This is the url I am calling.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/dashboard?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filters%5Bstart_date%5D=2017-01-01&filters%5Bend_date%5D=2017-01-01&%5Bwith_tax%5D=0&commit=Search
```

But it doesn't call this code, instead `self.records` is called. But If I change the code to support only one parameter, let's say `:start_date` and change `filters` to `filter` in the above code and the url, than it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issue with *filters* as well. So, I used two separate *filter* to achieve it instead.

1. The url should have filter keyword instead of filters. ie.

   ```
     json_api :get, api_tags_path, filter: {
       'start_date': 'start-date' ,
       'end_date': 'end-date',
     }
   ```

   Example: `http://www.example.com/api?filter[start_date]=start-date&filter[end_dat]=end-date`
2. And in the resource file:

   ```
   filter "start_date", apply: -> (records, value, _options){
        records.where('updated_at > ?', value[0])
   }

   filter "end_date", apply: -> (records, value, _options){
         records.where('updated_at < ?', value[0])
   }
   ```